# Why can't "asleep" be classified as a verb?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

Why can't "asleep" be classified as a verb?
English verbs include first of all the general implicit
meaning (the lexico-grammatical nature) of the verb which
serves to convey verbiality, i. e. different kinds of activity (go, read,
skate), various processes (boil, grow, obtain), the inner state of a person
(feel, bother, worry), possession (have, possess), etc.
The meaning of word asleep is also connected with action and process. Why can’t it be classified as a verb?

Comment: Give us an example sentence where you feel it's being used as a verb.

Comment: Asleep describes a state. Verbs denote activity.

Comment: +1 Very good question for a site for linguists and serious language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 7):

In English, verbs are words that take certain endings and can appear in certain constructions.

Verbs like *sleep, go, own,* or *be* have special forms:

- *sleep, sleeps, slept, sleeping*
- *go, goes, went, gone, going*
- *own, owns, owned, owning*
- *be, am, is, are, was, were, been, being*

that don't occur for other predicates

- **She asleeps*, **She aslept*, **She has aslept*, **She was asleeping*.

*Asleep* is an adjective that's formed from the verb *sleep*. Adjectives can be predicates (they're called *predicate adjectives* in that case), but adjectives can't take the endings that verbs can, so they have to use an auxiliary verb *be* that can be inflected.  The same is true of *predicate noun phrases* like *a doctor* or *solid rock*

- *That man is asleep/tired/tiring/dead/here/purple.*
- *That building is a clinic/solid rock/a monstrosity.*

So that's why *asleep* can't be a verb; it's already an adjective, and it can't work like a verb.

Comment: *When he found her, oh then they fell a-kissing.* As I was awalking, I saw a baby who was asleeping.

Comment: More seriously, I would argue that asleep was formed from the *noun* sleep, like *ashore, astern,* and *atop.*

Comment: For some creators, probly it was. For others, not. It doesn't get created once in a puff of smoke; it's a very gradual process, over hundreds of years, millions of people, and trillions of individual oral uses of _asleep_ to get to our present state of affairs. Which is changing at a glacial rate even as we discuss this.

Comment: +1 . Just to be devil's advocate for the sake of talking about grammar a bit more (which is why I come here), there is the case of *She was asleeping* and so forth ....

Comment: That's the regional _a_- participle prefix _Froggy would a-courting go, He's a-feared of snakes,_ etc. [A-prefixing](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/a-prefixing) is known in Appalachian speech groups, and there's a big literature about it in sociolinguistics.

Comment: I would add that A-prefixing doesn't have much to do with "asleep," if anything.  But I still don't see how anyone would form "asleep" from the verb.  Do we have any other examples of verbs taking an a- prefix to form an adjective?  The a- prefix here seems to be related to the preposition "at": she is at sleep; she is at shore; she is at (the) top, etc.  I also wonder whether this is related to above, around, about, etc. (prefixed versions of over, round, out, etc.).

Answer (score -3):

'Asleep' is equivalent to the participle 'sleeping'.  Neither one is a verb.  They are adjectives.  They do refer to an action, but 'asleep' (or 'at sleep') does it in an irregular way.

Comment: "Sleeping" is clearly a verb in "The baby is sleeping peacefully"; it's a gerund-participle verb-form and head of the non-finite clause "sleeping peacefully". It can't be an adjective because you can't say *"very sleeping peacefully"

Comment: @BillJ - But one could properly say "The baby is asleep peacefully".

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, but "asleep" is an adjective that can take post-head modifiers in the form of a adverbs. But "sleeping" can't be an adjective because it can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like *"She became/seemed sleeping", and as I mentioned before, it can't be modified by "very". Some participles, though, can also be adjectives, like "entertaining" for example, which can be complement to both complex-intransitive verbs: "It became quite entertaining", and complex-transitive verbs: "I found it quite entertaining"

Comment: @BillJ - Many words can be used as different and diverse parts of speech.  In many cases the nit-picking about what the construct "is someword" actually is is only a tap-dance around the fact that English grammar is quite imprecise and subject to interpretation.

Comment: @BillJ - 'sleeping' is a verbal, not a verb.  It can't be intensified because it is already as highly 'focused' as it can be.  'is sleeping' and 'is asleep' are both verb phrases, but the 'verb' is 'is'.  There is quite a difference between how verb phrases are built (messy) and how they are stored.

Comment: @Aml *verbal* is an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: @AmI _The baby is sleeping peacefully_ is simply a progressive construction, comprising the usual verb "be" + present participle. It is no different to _Ed is walking briskly_ and _Kim was writing a novel_. "Walking", "writing" and "sleeping" are clearly present participle verb-forms. There is no possibility of them being anything else.

Comment: 'Adjective' and 'adverbial' are also adjectives, not nouns; but I use them as nouns.  I also reject the term 'present participle', as there is nothing 'present' in 'the baby was sleeping'.  In 'the sleeping baby' the 'progressive participle' is used as an adjective.  In 'the baby is sleeping' the 'progressive participle' comes from applying the progressive aspect: suffix 'ing' to the 1st verbal and then prepend the word 'be' {which is changed to 'is' by the agreement process}.  -- 'Asleep' is clearly not a verb, but does it imply 'sleeping'?